What was Winning Strategies, Inc.?
Core libraries on many Linux and BSD based systems include copyright notices similar to this:

Copyright (c) 1993 Winning Strategies, Inc.
All rights reserved.
Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
are met:
... BSD 4-clause license conditions follow ...

Later commits from 1995 indicate that many pieces of code were released to public domain, presumably when the BSD 4-clause license fell out of favor.
I find the history of Winning Strategies particularly interesting, as it seems to be one of the earliest companies that heavily contributed to open source.
Some of the copyright messages credit the author as J.T. Conklin (jtc@wimsey.com), Winning Strategies, Inc. But unfortunately even the earliest archive.org snapshot of wimsey.com appears to be of a generic domain hoarder landing page.
What was Winning Strategies, Inc. about? Was its story more like Red Hat (profitable open source development) or like Netscape (open sourced only after the company ran out of money)?

I expect that's the same jtc who has been a NetBSD dev and who worked for Cygnus in the mid-90s. It would probably be possible to ask him :)

Nothing to chase down at wimsey.com; Wimsey was a Vancouver-based dialup ISP.
